# Jython code for deleting spaces from Text file

Tags: python, jython

I am trying to write a jython code for deleting spaces from Text file.I have a following scenario.
I have a text file like

```
STARTBUR001 20120416
20120416MES201667 20120320000000000201203210000000002012032200000000020120323000000000201203240000000002012032600000000020120327000000000201203280000000002012032900000000020120330000000000


20120416MES202566 2012030500000000020120306000000000201203070000000002012030800000000020120309000000000201203100000000002012031100000000020120312000000000201203130000000002012031400000000020


20120416MES275921 20120305000000000201203060000000002012030700000000020120308000000000201203090000000002012031000000000020120311000000000201203120000000002012031300000000020120314000000000

END 0000000202
```

Here all lines are single lines.
But what i want is like

```
STARTBUR001 20120416
20120416MES201667 20120320000000000201203210000000002012032200000000020120323000000000201203240000000002012032600000000020120327000000000201203280000000002012032900000000020120330000000000
20120416MES202566 2012030500000000020120306000000000201203070000000002012030800000000020120309000000000201203100000000002012031100000000020120312000000000201203130000000002012031400000000020
20120416MES275921 20120305000000000201203060000000002012030700000000020120308000000000201203090000000002012031000000000020120311000000000201203120000000002012031300000000020120314000000000
END 0000000202
```

So in all i want to start checking from second line till i encounter END and delete all spaces at tyhe end of each line.

Can someone guide me for writing this code??

tried like:

```
srcfile=open('d:/BUR001.txt','r')
trgtfile=open('d:/BUR002.txt','w')
readfile=srcfile.readline()
while readfile:
    trgtfile.write(readfile.replace('\s',''))
    readfile=srcfile.readline()
srcfile.close()
trgtfile.close()
```

Thanks,
Mahesh

Comment: tried like  srcfile=open('d:/BUR001.txt','r')
trgtfile=open('d:/BUR002.txt','w')
readfile=srcfile.readline()
while readfile:
    trgtfile.write(readfile.replace('\s',''))
    readfile=srcfile.readline()
srcfile.close()
trgtfile.close()

Answer (score 0):

You can use fact that those special lines starts with special values:

```
line = srcfile.readline()
while line:
    line2 = line
    if not line2.startswith('START') and not line2.startswith('END'):
        line2 = line2.replace(' ','')
    trgtfile.write(line2)
    line = srcfile.readline()
```

Also note that with `readline()` result strings ends with `\n` (or are empty at end of input file), and this code removes all spaces from the line, not only those at end of the line.

If I understood your example all you want is to remove empty lines, so instead of reading file line by line read it at once:

```
content = srcfile.read()
```

and then remove empty lines from content:

```
while '\n\n' in content:
    content = content.replace('\n\n', '\n')
```